# How to generate Axis2 source code in custom package

Tags: java, package, apache-axis

I am trying to generate Axis2 (v1.6.1) web service client code from multiple WSDL files so that I can have multiple web service clients within a single project. I'm using Ant to generate the source code using the codegen task.

Therefore, I need to use custom namespace to package mappings in order to keep each web service client's code discrete from the others to avoid clash.

Here's the namespaces from one example WSDL file:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.elster-eis.com/ImportExport"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.elster-eis.com/ImportExport"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<wsdl:types>
```

I've managed to get the main body of generated code into appropriate packages. And I've managed to get the soapenc namespace to generate in a custom package. However, I'm unable to get the code that is generating in `org\w3\www\_2004\_06\xmlmime` into my custom package's directory structure.

Here's the relevant parts of my Ant build file:

```
<property name="srv.pkg" value="com.company.webservice.mas" />

<property name="srv.mappings" value="http://www.elster-eis.com/ImportExport=${srv.pkg},http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema=${srv.pkg}.xsd,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/=${srv.pkg}.soap,http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/=${srv.pkg}.tm,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/=${srv.pkg}.soapenc,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/=${srv.pkg}.mime,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/=${srv.pkg}.soap12,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/=${srv.pkg}.http,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/=${srv.pkg}.wsdl" />

<target name="build.source" depends="define.tasks">
    <codegen
        wsdlfilename="${srv.wsdl}"
        packageName="${srv.pkg}"
        databindingName="xmlbeans"
        output="."
        generateAllClasses="true"
        serverside="true"
        generateservicexml="true"
        testcase="true"
        namespaceToPackages="${srv.mappings}"
    />
</target>
```

And here's the namespace to package mappings again for ease of reading (they're all on a single line, separated by commas, no spaces, in the Ant build file):

> http://www.elster-eis.com/ImportExport=${srv.pkg},
>
> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema=${srv.pkg}.xsd,
>
> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/=${srv.pkg}.soap,
>
> http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/=${srv.pkg}.tm,
>
> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/=${srv.pkg}.soapenc,
>
> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/=${srv.pkg}.mime,
>
> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/=${srv.pkg}.soap12,
>
> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/=${srv.pkg}.http,
>
> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/=${srv.pkg}.wsdl"

I'm trying to get ALL generated code to generate under my ${srv.pkg} structure, but the org.w3 code still generates under its own directory structure and my namespace mapping is being ignored.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Do you mean that axis generates your classes with incorrect package naming or just in incorrect directory?

Comment: @Andremoniy Both. They're in the org/w3, etc, directory and the package has the equivalent with respect to that structure.

Comment: I know, that's sounds silly, but did you try delete previously generated source code before running build?

Comment: @Andremoniy Yes, this is after cleaning and there's nothing there. I run my Ant build and it generates in that location every time. The soapenc namespace goes into my custom package and the main body of code from the WSDL itself goes into the custom package, just not the org.w3 code and I cannot for the life of me see why.

Comment: What do you mean by `org.w3 code` code?

Comment: The code that is generated under the directory I mentioned above: `org\w3\www_2004_06\xmlmime`. I need that generating under my custom package, if possible, rather than in that package/directory structure.

Comment: You could try building each wsdl as a separate ant target, with a single mapping for the wsdl/package, all outputting to the same classes folder,  Then another ant target to create single jar at end from the output classes folder.

Comment: @Sanj That's similar to what I'm attempting, as it happens, but the code is not entirely generating under my custom package structure, which is the problem I'm having here. Each WSDL's generated classes must go into different package structures. I can't have some classes going into the same package structure as another WSDL's generated source to avoid any clashing. My main application requires to make calls to multiple Axis2 based web services hence the requirement to keep each client's generated code entirely discrete as I'm certain I will encounter issues with XMLBeans as a result.

Comment: I could simply write my own SOAP web service client code without using Axis2 code generation at all, but it would be far less coding for me, if I can get the code from each service generated in discrete packages to allow me to easily import a jar or jars into my main application that will then use these generated classes.

Comment: To be clear, the mappings for `http://www.elster-eis.com/ImportExport` and `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/` are working fine, but the one that generates source in `org\w3\www\_2004\_06\xmlmime` clearly isn't. Not sure which mapping isn't working. I'm assuming it's the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` one, but I'm not certain of that.

Comment: Finally got it working. Posted an answer below for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it working. I looked inside the contents of the generated source files and found that it describes the actual namespace that the file was generated from. So, I just added THAT namespace (`http://www.w3.org/2004/06/xmlmime`) to my mapping and it works fine now.

So, the final operational namespace mappings are:

```
    <property name="srv.mappings" value="http://www.elster-eis.com/ImportExport=${srv.pkg},http://www.w3.org/2004/06/xmlmime=${srv.pkg}.xmlmime,http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/=${srv.pkg}.soapenc" />
```

After doing that, the generated source now shows this in its header:

```
/*
 * An XML attribute type.
 * Localname: contentType
 * Namespace: http://www.w3.org/2004/06/xmlmime
 * Java type: com.csa.webservice.mas.xmlmime.ContentTypeAttribute
 *
 * Automatically generated - do not modify.
 */
package com.csa.webservice.mas.xmlmime;
```